# Possible for awk to only output if 4 characters long?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

If I do

```
awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

then I get all the usernames.

**Question**

Is it possible to get awk only to output those that are 4 characters long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the length function:

```
awk -F: 'length($1)==4{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: hmm, length is better option, it does not require heavier regex parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk -F: '( $1 ~ /^....$/ ){print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F -lane 'print $F[0] if(length($F[0])==4)' /etc/passwd
```